# is it OK to lay an engineered wood floor that is 27' long without putting a T-joint in the middle to avoid buckling?

Tags: wood, floor, installation

I am installing an engineered wood floor (bamboo).  My LR/DR is 27' long.  The installer said I ned to put in a T-joint transition between the LR and DR, at the 18' mark, to avoid buckling.  I am concerned about a bump in the middle of the floor, and my wife says no way.  Do I need to do this? I am installing the floor parallel to the long side of the room.

Comment: are you sure the installer is going off of manufacturer recommendations and not his own experience? check with the floor manufacturer, they should be able to give you the actual numbers. my laminate floors' installation instructions asked for a joint at 13meters or 40feet. 18feet subjectively looks way too tiny a distance, and many open concept homes nowadays are much longer than that.

Comment: alt told you everything you need to know....manufacturer should give you recommendation. You should know that they always make "reserve" for themselves meaning that distance they tell you are most likely a bit smaller than it really should be, but if possible follow their instruction. @ alt why don't you post this as an answer?

Comment: If your decor allows, you could cheat yourself a large gap at the walls by removing (undercutting) drywall, applying normal baseboard, and then putting a largish quarter round shoe molding on that. This would give you at least an inch.

Comment: Is this floating, glue, or stapled?

Answer (score 1):

In my own personal experience of this, the floor is capable of enormous movement,
even if you undercut at the skirtings. Avoid long, expanses without expansion joints if possible. My floor used to rise, like a small hill, then open into canyons, dependent on the change in the weather and humidity. Remember too, being on edge, it's strong enough to push a wall down!